# URL Rewrite on debian not working

Tags: debian, ssh, url

When trying to enable URL rewrite I just can't get it to work. I've enabled it with the command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and I've restarted the service using `sudo service apache2 restart`. However in the root folder, nor in the sub folders, URL rewrite is not working.

PS: I get this as an answer from the server when using the `sudo a2enmod rewrite` command:

```
Module rewrite already enabled
```

On request:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: make sure that rewrite module is enabled in your httpd.conf and properly configured.

Comment: Whereabout is the httpd.conf in apache2 ( debian - stock debianLAMP edition )
PS:
I did 'locate httpd.conf' and it didn't find anything.

Comment: sorry, in debian the apache config file should be under `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Can't find the mod_rewrite function in the apache2.conf file.

Comment: after you issue `sudo a2enmod rewrite` check if there is a symbolic link in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Sep 24 17:07 rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default installation of Apache2 comes with mod_rewrite installed. To check whether this is the case, verify the existence of /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load.

```
      $ cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load

       LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

To enable and load mod_rewrite, do the rest of steps.

```
      $ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

The above command will create a symbolic link in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.

```
   $ ls -al /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Dec  9 23:10   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load
```

Then open up the following file, and replace every occurrence of "AllowOverride None" with "AllowOverride all".

```
      $ sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Finally, restart Apache2

Here is an example of .htaccess file

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule index.php / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yeah - followed this guide - didn't help me. It's still not working.

Comment: in the apache config you can make sure that `RewriteEngine On` is defined and also check the rewrite error log file

Comment: Whereabout is it? I don't know much about Apache ( LAMPP )

Comment: PS: It's not defined.

Comment: can you load your /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file here

Comment: Added it in the main question.

Comment: You can also add `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess file

Comment: Could you write an example .htaccess file? I'm trying to install a game panel - but all instruction fail, and I've got no clue.

Comment: btw, How do you know if your rewrite rule is not working?

Comment: I figured it out -> I included an offline caching plugin to my website. It didn't give me a fresh update - after many tries I uninstalled that from my webserver and I was good to go.